# Extract code and convert special characters to HTML entities

Tags: php, algorithm, strings, security

I want users to enter their code into my blog and keep original styling tags intact. So I had to develop a function that extracts user's code (between two tags) and convert special characters to HTML entities, then remove unwanted tags using `purifyHTML`.

I want to know if it is safe to use it like that, and if there are any bad issues with this function.

```
public function extracter($string, $start, $end){
    function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
        $delimiters = array();
        $ini = strpos($string,$start);
        if ($ini == 0) return FALSE;
        $delimiters['start'] = substr($string, 0, $ini);
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $last = strpos($string,$end,$ini);
        $len =  $last - $ini;
        $delimiters['inside'] = substr($string,$ini,$len);
        $delimiters['end'] = substr($string, $last+strlen($end));
        return $delimiters;
    }
    function reconstruct($strings = array(), $filter){
        if( count($strings) == 0 || !$strings )
            return false;
        $count = count($strings);
        $i = 0;
        $str = '';
        $code = array();
        $uniq = uniqid();//i create a unique key to prevent confusion if users insert the same token i'm using
        foreach ($strings as $key => $val) {
            $i++;
            foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
                if( $k == 'start' )
                    $str .= $v;
                if( $k == 'inside' ){
                    $str .= '['.$uniq.$i.']'; //creat a token in the string
                    $code[$i] = htmlspecialchars($v);
                }
                if( $i == $count )
                    if( $k == 'end' )
                        $str .= $v;
            }
        }
        $purify = $filter->purifyHtml($str);//i'm using purifyhtml to remove undesirable tags and leave TinyMce tags
        for ($j=1; $j <= $i; $j++) {
            $purify = str_replace('['.$uniq.$j.']', $code[$j], $purify); //replace the token with the escaped code
        }
        return $purify;
    }
    /* main */
    $string = " ".$string;
    $components = array();
    $exists = TRUE;
    while ( $exists ) {
        $st = get_string_between($string, $start, $end);//decompose if token found
        if( !$st )
            return $string;// return the original string if nothing found
        $string = $st['end'];
        $components[] = $st;
        $exists = strpos($st['end'], $start) !== FALSE;//check if another code exists in the string
    }

    return reconstruct($components, $this->InputFilter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Extracter" [should be spelled "extractor"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=extracter%2C+extractor).

It's nice that you broke up the functionality into smaller functions.

---

In `get_string_between()`, you don't appear to be properly handling the `$start` and `$end` strings not being found.  Consider:

```
$ini = strpos($string,$start);
if ($ini == 0) return FALSE;
```

Did you mean to write

```
if ($ini === FALSE) return FALSE;
```

instead?  [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) is tricky, in that you have to carefully distinguish between 0 and `FALSE` return values.

For `$last = strpos($string,$end,$ini)`, you don't check the return value at all, and just use it.

---

Flag variables are an ineffective way to control execution flow.  If possible, restructure the code to avoid them.  For example,

```
$components = array();
$exists = TRUE;
while ( $exists ) {
    $st = get_string_between($string, $start, $end);//decompose if token found
    if( !$st )
        return $string;// return the original string if nothing found
    $string = $st['end'];
    $components[] = $st;        $exists = strpos($st['end'], $start) !== FALSE;//check if another code exists in the string
}
```

… should be written as an equivalent do-while loop:

```
$components = array();
do {
    $st = get_string_between($string, $start, $end);//decompose if token found
    if( !$st )
        return $string;// return the original string if nothing found
    $string = $st['end'];
    $components[] = $st;
} while (strpos($st['end'], $start) !== FALSE); //check if another code exists in the string
```

However, even that is dissatisfying, since the `strpos()` test is redundant with the `strpos()` operation within `get_string_between()`.

```
$components = array();
while (($st = get_string_between($string, $start, $end))) {
    $components[] = $st;
    $string = $st['end'];
}
return empty($components) ? $string    // return the original string if nothing found
                          : reconstruct($components, $this->InputFilter);
```

---

In `reconstruct()`, your loops are too complex.  The original code…

```
$count = count($strings);
$i = 0;
$str = '';
$code = array();
$uniq = uniqid();//i create a unique key to prevent confusion if users insert the same token i'm using
foreach ($strings as $key => $val) {
    $i++;
    foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
        if( $k == 'start' )
            $str .= $v;
        if( $k == 'inside' ){
            $str .= '['.$uniq.$i.']'; //creat a token in the string
            $code[$i] = htmlspecialchars($v);
        }
        if( $i == $count )
            if( $k == 'end' )
                $str .= $v;
    }
}
```

… could be simplified to

```
$str = '';
$code = array();
$uniq = uniqid();
foreach ($strings as $i => $component) {
    $str .= $component['start'];
    $str .= "[$uniq" . ($i + 1) . "]";  // Create a token in the string
    $code[$i + 1] = htmlspecialchars($component['inside']);
}
$str .= $component[count($component) - 1]['end'];
```

It's unconventional that `$code` is a 1-based array, and there doesn't seem to be any advantage to starting from 1 rather than 0, so just use `$i` instead of `$i + 1` everywhere.  Just adjust `$j` accordingly.

---

Nobody likes to read low-level string manipulation code, especially when it's not clear what the code is supposed to do.  Now that I've understood it, I would write a comment on the function like this:

```
/**
 * Runs HTML purifier on $string.  Sections of the string between $start
 * and $end delimiters are taken literally: instead of being filtered through
 * the HTML purifier, they are escaped using htmlspecialchars() instead.
 * The $start and $end delimiters themselves are discarded.
 */
```